# TypeORM TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm implementing TypeORM with Typescript, and trying to create a service that extends the TypeORM repository:

```js
export class UserService extends Repository<User> {

  // ... my other service methods

}
```

After that I'm trying to call the repository `findOne` method from service (`userService.findOne(...)`), but I have a TypeORM error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at UserService.Repository.findOne (node_modules/typeorm/repository/Repository.js:174:29)
```

In the TypeORM library at this line, I understand that the `manager` is undefined:

```js
Repository.prototype.findOne = function (optionsOrConditions, maybeOptions) {
    return this.manager.findOne(this.metadata.target, optionsOrConditions, maybeOptions);
};
```

Below my TypeORM configuration:

```js
createConnection({
    type: "mysql",
    url: "...",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [ User ],
    cli: { entitiesDir: "src/models" },
})
```

Does someone had the same issue, or did I missed something in the configuration?
Thank you in advance!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my ormconfiguration did not take into account js files when running in production
Before I had:

```
 entities: ["${rootDir}/entities/**/*.ts"],
 migrations: ["${rootDir}/database/migrations/**/*.ts"],
 subscribers: ["${rootDir}/database/subscribers/**/*.ts"],
```

After:

```
 entities: ["${rootDir}/entities/**/*.{js,ts}"],
 migrations: ["${rootDir}/database/migrations/**/*.{js,ts}"],
 subscribers: ["${rootDir}/database/subscribers/**/*.{js,ts}"],
```

Notice the difference .ts and .{js,ts}